# Convert MusicXML to MIDI in browser using music21j

Tags: javascript, html, es6-modules, music21

I'm trying to load [music21j](https://github.com/cuthbertLab/music21j) in the browser (successful), and then convert an uncompressed MusicXML string into a MIDI file using the converter (not successful).

```
<script> 
  import * as music21j from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/music21j/+esm';
  console.log(music21j.default.converter.parse());

  // now how do I pass a MusicXML string to music21j and get midi back?

</script>
```

The code above displays the message `Loading Instrument: audio will begin when this message disappears` in the HTML.  However, I'm not trying to load any audio -- in fact, I'd like to avoid loading any soundfonts, and simply have music21j available as a conversion tool.

So, to summarize: **how can I simply pass an XML string to music21j and convert it to MIDI?**

Thanks for any clarification!

Comment: Music21j doesn't yet have a MIDI file export feature.  Because the browser version of music21 is mostly used so that you can see notation immediately and hear it as music, file generating export has been a low priority for the team.

Comment: @MichaelScottAsatoCuthbert Good to know!  I'll just mention that, as a use-case for supporting midi export, it can be nice to do playback via a library of choice, or to manipulate the midi directly using the browser APIs.

Comment: Definitely -- it's on a list of improvements to eventually get to, but since no one had mentioned wanting it, it was very low priority.  Now it'll be a somewhat higher priority.  But probably not till 2023 at earliest unless it gets funded.

Comment: @MichaelScottAsatoCuthbert May I ask: is there a page detailing the funding process?  If not, what's the procedure?

Comment: https://web.mit.edu/music21/doc/about/faq.html#consulting (that's all I'll say on the subject -- don't want to be flagged for advertising for money here on SO.